# Why can not use "return lhs.size() == rhs.size()" in std::sort() compare function?

Tags: c++

As title said, I wrote a test demo

```
bool comp(string lhs, string rhs) {
    return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
}

bool comp1(string lhs, string rhs) {
    return lhs.size() == rhs.size();
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    string str[] = {"dog", "is", "cat", "elephant", "fish", "cow"};
    std::sort(str, str + 6, comp1);
    output();
}
```

output:`cat dog is elephant fish cow`

expected:`...cat dog cow...`

I want to put those same size strings together, but it didn't work, what's problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings

Comment: What is the output you recieve?

Comment: What do you mean by "put the same size strings together"? Isn't sorting with your first `comp` function doing just that?

Comment: Because equality is not an ordering. What's wrong with the first function?

Comment: Your parameters are `a` and `b` and you are trying to compare `lhs` and `rhs`.

Comment: The comparator tells it which items go *before* which items. If you do use `==`, you're saying that "a" goes before "b", and "b" goes before "a", and "aa" doesn't go before "a", and "a" doesn't go before "aa". How's it supposed to sort things so that "a" goes both before *and* after "b"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `comp1(a,b)` and `comp1(b,a)` can both return `true`, which isn't allowed. [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) states that:

> comp   -   comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare)) which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second.

And following the link to [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) we also see:

> Establishes [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) relation with the following properties
>   * For all a, comp(a,a)==false
>   * If comp(a,b)==true then comp(b,a)==false
>   * if comp(a,b)==true and comp(b,c)==true then comp(a,c)==true

Your first function, `comp`, satisfies those requirements: no two objects could return `true`. If `comp(a,b)` returns `true,` then `comp(b,a)` returns `false`; however, this is not the case in your second function, `comp1`. `comp1(a,b)` can return `true`, as can `comp(b,a)`, so `sort` will never finish and therefore it won't compile.

You state that

> i want to put those same size strings together

But just using `operator<` will achieve those results: any string the same size will be grouped together.

Comment: `comp(a,b)` and `comp(b,a)` are allowed to return the same result. As long as that result is false, which would be the case for equivalent values.

Answer (score 2):

`==` does not form a [strict weak order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). The following should be ideal per your description:

```
bool comp(string const& lhs, string const& rhs) {
    return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
}
```

Or if you want lexicographical sorting for strings of the same length:

```
bool comp(string const& lhs, string const& rhs) {
    return
        lhs.size() < rhs.size()
     || (lhs.size() == rhs.size() && lhs < rhs);
}
```

For further reading, here's my favorite article on the topic: [Order I Say!](https://web.archive.org/web/20120422220137/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/02/order-i-say/)

Comment: When you introduce unrelated changes like changing the parameter types to `const &`, it's helpful to explain why. Other than that, your changed `comp1` is what the OP does know works: it's the OP's `comp` function.